# rails 2.3.8 and activesupport runtime error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle

this is the error im getting when i "script/server":

```
can't activate activesupport (= 3.0.0, runtime) for [], already activated activesupport-2.3.8 for ["rails-2.3.8"]
```

i THINK whats happening here is that something is trying to call in / active "activesupport" for 3.0.0 ... when the "activesupport" for 2.3.8 is already working?

helps?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need uninstall rails 3.0.0 and activesupport 3.0.0.

You can use some different gemset with rvm by example.

Another solution is using bundler with a specific rails version define inside.

If you use bundler you need launch your server with bundler

```
bundle exec script/server
```

Comment: source :gemcutter

gem "rails", "2.3.8"
gem "activesupport", "2.3.8"
gem "rake", "0.8.7"
gem "activesupport", "2.3.8" 
gem "rack", "1.1.0" 
gem "actionpack", "2.3.8" 
gem "actionmailer", "2.3.8" 
gem "activerecord", "2.3.8" 
gem "activeresource", "2.3.8" 
gem "rails", "2.3.8" 
gem "bundler", "1.0.0"
gem "linkedin", "0.1.7"

Comment: ok i THINK i fixed the wrong version of rails and activesupport .. but now i think ive got further activesupport errors  http://pastie.org/1306362

Comment: trye bundle exec script/server